# _OBJ_CLASS_$_project name in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Greetings of the Day,

In my app i am trying to integrate slider which is done successfully but i am getting error

> Undefined symbols:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_project name",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-project name in Detailed.o ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

which is in NSObject.h:146 :

```
@interface NSObject (NSDiscardableContentProxy)

- (id)autoContentAccessingProxy NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);

@end
```

i am not getting how rectify the issue.Please help me!!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you have showed is not helpful towards solving your problem. Please post the code where you are "trying to integrate slider" in your application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please remove file "Detailed.h/m" from your code if you drag/drop from other project direct and add them again.

Comment: Are you sure by removing the file will it work and one thing i am doing through code.Answer the question then only if you have confidence.

Comment: @ManjotSingh As this seems to be an old issue, did you solve it? If yes, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Deepak I left the issue because I didn't get any solution for it.

Comment: @ManjitSingh: What's with the attitude mate! I think we all are trying to help each other at end of the day... the proposed solution is something that worked for me... If it's not working for you then it's HARD LUCK!

Comment: @Prabh that is not an attitude friend still I am not able to solve this issue and already did that solution which you gave me earlier but no use.After that I remake the whole app then this error gone I even dont how did it gone :)

Comment: @ManjitSingh: Unless you don't mention the solutions you have already tried then we can't make any discretion while suggesting. Either way, at times, newly added files are not added your Target of the application. You can also simply add them by right click on project's Target file and add them. This might also help you.